# Search for item iterating through multiple lists

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through multiple lists to find a "Directory". 
If I have a directory structure such as: 
/A/B/C

/A/D/F

It seems to work if I look for B or C, but fails for D and F. I think this is because when it encounters a situation where it is searching down a list and it doesn't find the correct Directory then it doesn't know what to return (or if I uncomment the return NULL it returns null, which I don't want it to because it doesn't mean it's not technically found).

I.E. If I search for F, it will search A/B/C and not know what to return.

Is there a way to hold off on the return value until it finds a directory or until it is finished looking?

```
Directory* search_tree_for_dir(string dir_name) {
            for(list<Directory*>::iterator iter = this->l_dir.begin(); iter != this->l_dir.end(); iter++) {
                  // Base case: if directory found then return
                  if((*iter)->name == dir_name){
                      return *iter;
                  }
                  if(*iter != NULL) { 
                      return (*iter)->search_tree_for_dir(dir_name);
                  }
              } 
              //return NULL;
          }
```

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to look up tree traversals like Post Order Traversal. link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is check the return value of your recursive call, and see what it returns. For example:

```
Directory *ret = (*iter)->search_tree_for_dir(dir_name);
if (ret) {
    return ret;
}
```

That way, if the recursive call returns something other than `NULL`, you will pass it on. If it doesn't find anything (i.e. it returns `NULL`) then you don't pass it on, and you keep searching.